# Angular 6: Routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Не уверен, но, похоже, проблема именно с маршрутизацией. До внедрения `RouterModule` все работало. Делаю поиск. Есть две компоненты - `search` и `searchresult`.

> search.component.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="query" type="text" placeholder="Поиск продукта...">
  <button (click)="link_search(query)">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

> search.component.ts

```
  link_search(search: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/searchresults/' + search);
}
```

> search-result.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.query = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('query');        
    this.search(this.query);       
  }
```

> метод search

```
search(query: string) {
      this.searchService.getDefault(query).subscribe(
        data => this.searchResult = data);            
  }
```

Данные из API приходят 100%, но после выполнения метода `this.searchResult` все равно пуст. Если вызвать метод поиска из компоненты search-result кнопкой (т.е. когда компонент уже проинициализирован) то данные в `this.searchResult` есть, правда не работает пагинация.

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DefaultComponent },
  { path: 'searchresults/:query', component: SearchresultComponent },
```

Часть кода убрана, для читаемости (проверки и тд). Ангуляр изучаю недавно, возмонжо упускаю как-то базовый момент. Что делаю не так? Повторю, до добавления рутинга, когда внутри одной компоненты вызывал другую с передачей массива данных все работало как надо

Comment: если в `subscribe` сделать `console.log(data)` - что выводит консоль?

Comment: Артур, уже делал. Выводит ровно то, что надо, т.е. некий массив с данными. имхо, странность в том, что вызов метода из ngOnInit возвращает пустой массив. Если его же вызвать уже со страницы, то массив забит. При этом в обоих случаях в консоль приходит один и тот же набор данных, т.е. все отлично

Comment: то есть если с `DefaultComponent` перейти на `searchresults/qwerty`, то в консоли ничего, а если сразу в урле ввести `searchresults/qwerty`, то данные есть в консоли?

Comment: Не совсем. В консоле всегда все хорошо, т.е. нужная инфа. Как переходить в компонент, не важно, в консоли будет инфа, в массиве нет. А если вызвать метод со страницы search-result.component.html типа так `<button (click)="search('qwerty')">
  <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
</button>` то и в косоли будет инфа и в массиве

Comment: Сам подход в организации брал отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992002/angular2-5-search-a-database-and-display-results-on-new-page. Попробую в stackblitz накидать свой код

Comment: да, так будет лучше, используйте для АПИ jsonplaceholdedr

Comment: Блин, похоже не смогу. Кидает ошибки на импорта. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtpubh еще поковыряю

Comment: `HttpClientModule` в `imports` надо, а не `HttpClient`

Comment: Сделал. Правда в моем проекте пагинатор не работает, здесь норм. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtpubh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте пройдемся поэтапно по вашей проблеме.

1) Когда вы пытаетесь перейти на один и тот же компонент, допустим в данный момент вы на `/searchresults/aa`, ввели что-то в инпут, кликаете на кнопку, запускается обработчик события в котором вызывается `this.router.navigate(['searchresults', query])`, то `RouterOutlet` не будет инициализировать этот компонент дважды или n раз, это называется `reuse`. То есть конструктор вызывается единожды вместе с крюками жизненного цикла, заканчивающиеся на `Init` (`ngOnInit || ngAfterViewInit || etc.`). В данном случае нужно делать подписку на смену параметров в URL:

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Params } from '@angular/router';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';

export class SearchresultComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(({ query }: Params) => {
            if (!query) {
                return;
            }

            this.search(query);
        });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }

    // .... где-то тут ваш метод `search`
}
```

То есть каждый раз как в URL меняется параметр `searchresults/:query` - поток `params` генерирует событие и компонент об этом узнает, а далее вызывается ваш метод `search`.

2) Немного подкорректируем ваш метод `search`. На заметку: всегда конвертируйте HTTP потоки в `Promise`, поверьте, с этим НАМНОГО удобнее работать, в ближайшем будущем вы попробуете это на вкус.

```
public search(query: string): void {
    this.searchService.getDefault(query).toPromise().then((data) => {
        this.searchResult = data;

        if (!this.searchResult) {
            return;
        }

        this.length = this.searchResult.length;
        this.changePageEvent();
    }).catch((e: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Empty results...';
        if (e.status === 204) {
            this.statusCode = e.status;
        }
    });
}
```

И вуаля - мы видим наши результаты при переходе с `/` URL.